# the multiplication of digits squares of numbers in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-manipulation

I want to obtain a list that provides specific requirements from a range
**my code** can only multiply digits of numbers in a list.
I want to get multiply "digits squares" of numbers in a list

For example:
A range defined = (1,200)

wanted_list =[1^2,2^2,3^2,...,(34 = 3^2 * 4^2),(35 = 3^2 * 5^2),...,(199 = 1^2 * 9^2 * 9^2)]

Here is **my code**:

```
def mult(liste):
    a=1
    for i in liste:
        a*=i       #I think the problem is here
    return a

listemm = [x for x in range(1,200)]
print(listemm)
qe= [mult(int(digit) for digit in str(numb)) for numb in listemm]
print(qe)
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: One quick and hacky solution is to convert your integers to an iterable such as string, in this case, and calculate the multiplication of their square. Otherwise you have to extract the digits from integers using the proper mathematical way  by dividing by 10 and preserving the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
r = range(1, 200)


def reduce_prod(n):
    p = 1
    for i in str(n):
        p *= int(i)**2
    return p


wanted_list = [reduce_prod(x) for x in r]
```

which produces:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 0, 1, ...]
#                                 ^
#                                 from 10 -> 1^2 * 0^2 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. Here is the corrected version of your own attempt for range up to 30. The problem was that your function worked for only two digits. Here I am using if-else condition to check if the number is less than 10. In case it is, I simply square it else I send it to your function.

In the function, you were not squaring the numbers. You also don't need `listemm`. You can directly use `range` in your list comprehension.

```
def mult(liste):
    a=1
    for i in liste:
        a*=i**2       # Square here (the problem was partly here)
    return a

qe= [numb**2 if numb<10 else mult(int(digit) for digit in str(numb)) for numb in range(1,30)]
print(qe)

# [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 0, 4, 16, 36, 64, 100, 144, 196, 256, 324]
```